# How does stackable pattern, in Scala, apply when you need more parameters

Tags: scala, design-patterns

Following the canonical example for stackable traits[1]:

```
trait Double extends IntQueue {
  abstract override def put(x: Int) { super.put(2 * x) }
}
```

What if I wanted the constant '2' to be set dymically?

I have two solutions but with rather big downsides:

1. Add method `putMultiplied` to new trait `MultiplyX`

   ```
   trait Multiplier extends IntQueue {
     abstract override def putMultiplied(constant: Int, x: Int) { super.put(constant * x) }
   }
   ```

   However this destroys the stackable property, because another stackable trait would have to know the `putMultiplied` method
2. Make a setter for the constant:

   ```
   trait Multiplier extends IntQueue {
     var constant //hihi a variable constant
     abstract override def put(x: Int) { super.put(constant * x)  }
   }
   ```

   However this seems weird, and puts the burden on the caller to remember to set `constant` before every invocation.

Intuitively I would want the trait to have a constructor parameter:

```
    trait Multiplier(val constant: Int) extends IntQueue {
      abstract override def put(x: Int) { super.put(constant * x)  }
    }
```

But alas we all know traits do not support parameters.

Am I asking too much of this pattern in combination with Scala traits?
How would this be solved?

[1] http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/stackable_trait_pattern.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it another method:

```
   trait Multiplied extends IntQueue {
      def multiplier = 2
      abstract override def put(x: Int) { super.put(multiplier * x) }
   }
```

You can then instantiate it like this:

```
   val triplingQueue = new ActualQueue with Multiplier {
      override def multiplier = 3
   }
```